# Prevent CaptureElement from trying to take on size of image and pushing out scrollviewer

Tags: graphics, uwp

I have a container hierarchy which includes a scrollviewer towards the top so I can see my entire form. Inside, I can a CaptureElement which when started connects to the webcam at 640*480 resolution.

The behavior I see, which I don't want and seem unable to prevent, is that the captureelement tries to take on a render size the same as the image resolution, 640 * 480, even when it is set to stretch. So it will push out all of the containers up to the one with the scrollviewer. I want it to behave like other controls, like Button, etc, where it just takes the available inner size, and the scrollviewer only takes part if it really has to.

This is all demonstrated by the code below, but comment / uncomment to see the button instead of the CaptureElement:

```
Inherits Page

Private mc As New MediaCapture
Private ce As New CaptureElement

Private WithEvents TopGrid As New Grid
Private vs As New ScrollViewer
Private WithEvents CamGrid As New Grid

Private but As New Button

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    Content = TopGrid

    TopGrid.Width = 600
    TopGrid.Height = 200
    TopGrid.Children.Add(vs)
    vs.Content = CamGrid
    vs.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible
    vs.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible

    but.Content = "hello"

    but.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
    but.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch
    ce.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
    but.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch

    InitCam()


    CamGrid.Children.Add(ce)
    'CamGrid.Children.Add(but)

End Sub

Private Async Sub InitCam()
    Await mc.InitializeAsync
    ce.Source = mc
    Dim t = mc.StartPreviewAsync
End Sub

Private Sub CamGrid_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As SizeChangedEventArgs) Handles CamGrid.SizeChanged
    Dim w = e.NewSize.Width
    Dim h = e.NewSize.Height
    Dim a = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: You must set a height for the `CaptureElement` or it will get the default preview size.You already know the `TopGrid` height is 200, so why not directly set it ? ` ce.Height=200`

Comment: The code above is just an example - in realty, the outer container always has some kind of fixed size, perhaps the form size. But I want this to be fluid, not a fixed size. I just want the CaptureElement to behave consistently with other controls - and not push out srcollviewers just because of the resolution of the image displayed. I'm happy to nest it inside other containers if that works but I don't want anything to have fixed sizes

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found an answer. Use a canvas for controls you want to manage the size of, within higher level scrollviewers. Canvas does not expand to contain it's children, so does not result in conflict / recursion.